# Seleccionar suma de registros por id con PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero mediante una consulta traer la suma de unos registros, pero quiero que sean los registros solo de X elemento.

Lo que quiero es mediante un formulario con ajax seleccionar un vehículo, el cual lo tengo identificado por id_vehiculo, para que la consulta me devuelva la suma de los servicios de ese vehículo en especifico.

Este es el código:

```
include_once('conexion.php');
class Procesar extends Model{

    public function __construct(){ 
        parent::__construct(); 
    }

    public function build_report($year){
        $total = array();
        for($i=0; $i<12; $i++){
            $month = $i+1;
            $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(utilidad_servicio) AS total FROM servicios_vehiculos WHERE MONTH(fecha_servicio) = '$month' AND YEAR(fecha_servicio) = '$year' LIMIT 1");   
            $total[$i] = 0;
            foreach ($sql as $key){ $total[$i] = ($key['total'] == null)? 0 : $key['total']; }
        }            
        return $total;
    }

}

if($_POST['year']){
    $class = new Procesar;
    $run = $class->build_report($_POST['year']);
    exit(json_encode($run));
}
```

Comment: No se te entendió bien en el planteamiento de la pregunta. Puedes agregar a la consulta un `GROUP BY lacolumnaiddelelemento` y quizá también poner esa columna en el `WHERE` quitando el `LIMIT 1`, digo quizá porque no se entiende del todo lo que quieres. Otra cosa: tu código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL, debes usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: ÇQue error te tira la consulta?

Comment: Y bien, ¿cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que cambiar tu función `build_report`. No solo agregarle al `WHERE` el **id_vehiculo** que quieres buscar, si no quitando la consulta del bucle y haciendo las **[consultas preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)**:

```
public function build_report($year){
    $total = array();
    $prepare = $this->db->prepare("SELECT
                                        SUM(utilidad_servicio) AS total
                                        , MONTH(fecha_servicio) AS mes
                                    FROM
                                        servicios_vehiculos
                                    WHERE
                                        YEAR(fecha_servicio) = ?
                                        AND id_vehiculo = ?
                                    GROUP BY
                                        MONTH(fecha_servicio)");  
    $prepare->bind_baram("ii", $year, $id_vehiculo); // Contando que el id_vehículo sea un int
    $prepare->execute();
    $prepare->bind_result($total, $mes);
    while ($prepare->fetch()){
        $total[$mes] = is_null($total) ? 0 : $total;
        // $total[$mes] = $total ?? 0; // en el caso de usar PHP 7+
    }
    return $total;
}
```

**No he probado el código** pero debería ser casi así.